# non-ponzi condition

Tags: macroeconomics, microeconomics, econometrics, economic-growth, endogenous-growth

What Is The Differences Between R(T) And R(S) In No-Ponzi Condition In Ramsey Growth Model?
[image]

Comment: You asked several questions. Maybe you can accept some that were answered in the past?